# very slow boot (6m), how to force change `systemd-udevd` timeout to 5s?

Tags: boot, grub2, udev

Essentially what is happening is this:

to the `linux` grub command, I added `debug --verbose` and got this!

after 60s waiting:
`systemd-udevd 'SomeDevicePartition' is taking a long time`

after more 120s:
`systemd-udevd 'SomeDevicePartition' killed`

they happen at +- : 60s, 180s, 240s, 365s
so a total of 6minutes!!!

**I wonder if udevd killing timeout could be lowered to may be 10s and do not retry? (using some config in the grub entry)**

---

if you need more info, the whole problem details is here (above is just the essential part): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196874/18-04-grub-takes-about-6-minutes-to-boot-problem-systemd-udevd-somedevice

---

I got a tip to workaround it:
`udevadm --timeout=10`

but I may need to undo it using a LiveCD iso image so:
**Where `udevadm` stores it's configuration?** I tried `cat ./udev/rules.d/* |grep timeout -i` and it found nothing...

Also it is for generic events so, as a bonus: **is there some specific timeout I can configure for dealing with partition detection?**

---

here is what is in grub cfg:

```
linux /vmlinuz-4.15.0-72-generic \
  root=/dev/mapper/MyLvmGroupName ro \
  nosplash $vt_handoff debug --verbose
```

as a tip from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/559979/30352 (here), I tried:

```
linux /vmlinuz-4.15.0-72-generic \
  root=/dev/mapper/MyLvmGroupName ro \
  rd.udev.event-timeout=10 \
  nosplash $vt_handoff debug --verbose
```

but it seems to be ignored for some reason :( as I still have very long timouts (the same, nothing changed)

---

I am with this problem since +- 10/12/2019 :/ (The last time I did a full update on Ubuntu18)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your system use systemd's udev.

So, let's start to this service manpage (systemd-udevd.service(8)):

```
       The behavior of the daemon can be configured using udev.conf(5), its command line options,
       environment variables, and on the kernel command line, or changed dynamically with udevadm
       control.
```

And further:

```
KERNEL COMMAND LINE
       Parameters starting with "rd." will be read when systemd-udevd is used in an initrd.

       udev.log-priority=, rd.udev.log-priority=
           Set the log level.

       udev.children-max=, rd.udev.children-max=
           Limit the number of events executed in parallel.

       udev.exec-delay=, rd.udev.exec-delay=
           Delay the execution of RUN instructions by the given number of seconds. This option might
           be useful when debugging system crashes during coldplug caused by loading non-working
           kernel modules.

       udev.event-timeout=, rd.udev.event-timeout=
           Wait for events to finish up to the given number of seconds. This option might be useful
           if events are terminated due to kernel drivers taking too long to initialize.

       net.ifnames=
           Network interfaces are renamed to give them predictable names when possible. It is enabled
           by default; specifying 0 disables it.
```

So maybe you could try to add `udev.event-timeout=10` (or the same prefixed with `rd.` if the issue is on the initrd phase) to your kernel command line.

Comment: this worked, thx! `linux /vmlinuz-4.15.0-72-generic udev.event-timeout=5 root=/dev/mapper/MyLvmGroupName ro nosplash $vt_handoff debug --verbose`